# Bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

In Appendix B, Theorem B.3 of Introduction to Real Analysis by Bartle & Sherbert, we have to prove the existence of a function $\phi:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow A$, where $A\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ is a non empty and infinite, such that $\phi(n+1)\gt\phi(n) \geq n \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ and further prove that $\phi$ is bijective. 
In the last portion of the proof, where it is claimed that $\phi$ is surjective, we consider least element $p \in A'=A\setminus \phi(\mathbb{N})$, and we claim that $p \in \{\phi(1),\phi(2),\ldots, \phi(p) \}$. 
If the latter claim is false, then $p \in A\setminus\{\phi(1),\phi(2),\ldots, \phi(p) \} = A_{p} $. Till here, it is fine.

I couldn't understand what it is said further, that is $\phi(p+1)$ is the least element of $A_{p}$ and thus, $\phi(p+1)\leq p$ satisfies.

Since we are considering $A'=A\setminus \phi(\mathbb{N})$ to be non-empty, should we not consider the possibility that there might exist a number in $A_{p}$ which is less than $\phi(p+1)$ and doesn't belong to $\phi(\mathbb{N})$ i.e. $\phi(p+1)$ is not the least element of $A_{p}$.

Comment: You have not defined $A$.

Comment: I have defined it when I introduced $\phi$

Comment: No, you have not. You ask to prove there exists $\phi$ that has certain properties, among them that its image is called $A.$ What are the initial assumptions about $A, $ besides $A\subset \Bbb N$?

Comment: I suppose the hypothesis on $A$ is that $A$ is not empty and has no largest member. Is that it?

Comment: Yeah, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Although there is nothing wrong with using recursion (in which $\phi (n)$ is defined in terms of $\{\phi (m):m<n\}),$ I could give a longer proof using only induction. For $n\in \Bbb N$ define $[[n]]=\{m\in \Bbb N: m\le n\}.$ For $a\in A$ define $a^*=\{b\in A: b\le a\}.$ Now let $\phi(n)=a$ iff $a$ is the $unique$ $b\in A $ such that $[[n]]$ is bijective with $b^*.$  We must prove that the domain of $\phi$ is all of $\Bbb N,$ and has the other required properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that $\phi$ is recursively defined as $\phi(1) = \min A$, and $\phi(n+1) = \min (A\setminus \{\phi(1), \ldots, \phi(n)\})$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, using the well-ordering of $\mathbb{N}$.

If $p \notin \{\phi(1), \ldots, \phi(p)\}$, then $p \in A\setminus \{\phi(1), \ldots, \phi(p)\}$ so by definition
$$\phi(p+1) = \min (A\setminus \{\phi(1), \ldots, \phi(p)\}) \le p$$
since the minimum of the set is $\le$ than any particular element of the set.

But this is a contradiction with the property that $\phi(n+1) >  n, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. Hence $p \in  \{\phi(1), \ldots, \phi(p)\} \subseteq \phi(\mathbb{N})$.